The number of intersection points of two completely monotonic functions
Is there a way to show that two completely bounded decreasing monotonic function which are also differentiable over $[0,\infty)$ intersect at most at one point? or showing some counterexamples.
Completely monotonic functions satisfies $(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t)>0$~(I have slightly changed the definition and just looking for decreasing functions and not non-increasing).

That's not true.  For any $N$ we get $N$ zeros by choosing some sequence $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^N$ with $1 < c_1 < c_2 < c_3 < \cdots < c_N$, expanding $\delta(t) := \prod_{i=1}^N (1 - c_i e^{-t})$ as a linear combination of exponentials $e^{-mt}$ ($0 \leq m \leq N$), and separating into positive and negative parts to write $\delta(t) = f(t) - g(t)$ where $f,g$ are nonnegative linear combinations of $e^{-mt}$ and thus completely monotonic but $\delta$ vanishes at $\log c_i$ for each $i$.  One can probably even get infinitely many zeros.
